# Build an R package tarball without divulging your user name in the tarball

Tags: r, r-package

In `R CMD build`, the ID of the user is automatically inserted into the `DESCRIPTION` file. This is problematic because I work in a corporate computing environment and I do not want to divulge my user ID.

Reproducible example:

```
git clone git@github.com:tidyverse/reprex
R CMD build reprex
rm -rf reprex
tar -xf reprex*tar.gz
grep Packaged reprex/DESCRIPTION
```

Current output:

```
Packaged: 2018-11-06 14:01:50 UTC; <MY USER ID>
```

Desired output

```
Packaged: 2018-11-06 14:01:50 UTC;
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the name and re-compress it?

Comment: Doesn't seem too hard now that you mention it, but it still feels like something I should not have to clean out manually.

Comment: I added a one line script. That would be much easier than going and changing the internals, then you'll have to make changes every time you update your language. If you're using a build system, try adding this to it. 

Travis should have post build hooks and is free for opensource projects, try it, it's easy.

Or add the script as a bash alias so you don't have to type all of it everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of doing this internally, but, why don't you just remove the ID and repackage it?

```
git clone git@github.com:tidyverse/reprex
R CMD build reprex
rm -rf reprex
tar -xf reprex*tar.gz
grep -l "Packaged" reprex/DESCRIPTION | xargs sed  's/UTC;.*/UTC;/' >  reprex/DESCRIPTION
```

Now compress it again with tar. Probably add this to your build system.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the appropriate way to go. Reminds me of https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/492, actually.